# How to extend trial license for VS 2015 RC for offline PC?

Tags: licensing, offline, visual-studio-2015, rc

I was using VS 2015 CTP to try the migration of my project some time ago. After MS released VS 2015 RC I uninstalled CTP and installed VS 2015 RC. When I start installed VS, I'm getting the window:

License: Prerelease software
 This license has expired.
 Your trial has expired. Sign in to extend the trial and continue without interruption.

The problem is that my PC is not connected to internet according to corporate security reasons and I cannot change this. So I cannot Sign in, and I cannot "Check for an updated license" (which is another link in this window).

Do I have any chance (workaround) to use VS 2015 RC on this machine?

Comment: My license on VS 2015 Enterprise RC went to exired status today and is for me impossible to renew :/ i have pc connected to internet but there is no option to renew.. ://